# Get currency exchange rate using bash

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-interface

I would like to display the current exchange rate from the currency euro to us dollar in the command line using bash shell script. I'm using the website market insider.
I saw on someone's blog to use wget command

```
wget -qO- https://markets.businessinsider.com/currencies/eur-usd
```

But how can I display only the rate? Desired output (example for current rate 1.1347) --> 1.1347 $

PS: I would prefer not to use API

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `PS: I would prefer not to use API`: Could you elaborate on this restriction, since it seems totally counter-productive, as well as deleting your question and opening a duplicate here because the rating of it did not please you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70824478/get-exchange-rate-using-bash-shell-script

Comment: @LéaGris no I posted it here again because I got notification from stackoverflow that the post has been associated with another similar question and I should ask again if it's not answered yet. And this is a requirement not to use the API from above, so that's why I opened new question

Comment: "How do I scrape currency exchange rates from businessinsider?" is not really the kind of programming question SO deals with. Try rephrasing it in terms of the programming, such as "How do I get the line immediately after a regex match in the output of a shell command?"

Answer (score 4):

Do this cleanly using their API:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

API='https://markets.businessinsider.com/ajax/'

implode() { printf %s "$*";}

ExchangeRate_GetConversionForCurrenciesNumbers() {
  isoCodeForeign=$1
  isoCodeLocal=$2
  amount=$3
  date=$4
  cacheFile="/tmp/$date-$amount-$isoCodeForeign-$isoCodeLocal.json"

  # Check if we have cached the result to avoid front-running the API
  if ! [ -e "$cacheFile" ]; then
    post_vars=$(
      IFS=\& implode \
        "isoCodeForeign=$isoCodeForeign" \
        "isoCodeLocal=$isoCodeLocal" \
        "amount=$amount" \
        "date=$date"
    )

    method='ExchangeRate_GetConversionForCurrenciesNumbers'
    url="$API$method?$post_vars"
    if ! http_code=$(
      curl -s -w '%{http_code}' \
        -H 'Accept: application/json' \
        -X POST "$url" -o "$cacheFile"
    ); then
      printf 'Failed to connect to %s\n' "$API"
      rm -f "$cacheFile"
      return 1
    fi >&2
    if ! [ "$http_code" = '200' ]; then
      printf 'Unexpected http_code=%s from %s:\n' "$http_code" "POST $url"
      cat "$cacheFile"
      echo
      rm -f "$cacheFile"
      return 1
    fi >&2
  fi
  jq -r '.ConvertedAmountFourDigits' "$cacheFile"
}

getRateEURO_USToday() {
  ExchangeRate_GetConversionForCurrenciesNumbers EUR USD 1 "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')"
}

exchange_rate=$(getRateEURO_USToday) || exit 1
# Set LC_NUMERIC=C because the float format returned is using . as decimal
LC_NUMERIC=C printf 'The exchange rate for EUR to USD today is: %.4f\n' \
  "$exchange_rate"
```

Comment: This stopped working today.

Comment: APIs may become temporarily or definitely unavailable; often have rate and volume restrictions, witch tend to be much lower for free users; often 
@Mailman3.com legitimately protect themselves over abuses, by blocking access either temporarily or definitely to IP/Ranges. And finally, using a Web API is still using someone-else's computer. I tested it right now and it still works as it always did.

Comment: You are right, it was "Temporarily Unavailable" and then the result was cached making the impression that it doesn't work still ) After I've deleted the cache file it's recovered. Thank you

Comment: @Mailman3.com Updated the code with error handling and refactored to POSIX shell grammar rather than Bash dialect.

Comment: This is really nice @Léa Gris ! Thank you very much )